# Strange values of Math.Sin

Tags: c#, trigonometry

everyone!
I'm trying to plot sin-function 7sin(3t) in c#

```
PointF[] Points = new PointF[200];
int T = 20;   //t
Graphics gr;

private void calculatePoints()
        {
            gr = CreateGraphics();
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            Pen pen = new Pen(brush, 3);
            float xk, yk;        

            //k for scaling
            yk = (float)((this.ClientRectangle.Height - 40)/2) / 7;  
            xk = (float)(this.ClientRectangle.Width - 40) / (Points.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < Points.Length; i++)
            {    
                //here we go
                Points[i] = new PointF(20 + i * xk,
                                      this.ClientRectangle.Height/2 - (float) Math.Sin(3 * i * T) * 7 * yk);
            }
            gr.DrawCurve(pen, Points);
        }
```

So my curve is looking like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucpOV.png

But if I multiply argument of sin by 180 for example, I will get a nice plot. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K26KE.png

Could you help me with that, please?

Comment: It's because [Radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)

Comment: As @Blorgbeard very correctly says; most *actual* geometric maths (outside of grade school) uses radians, not degrees. The good news is you can just multiply to convert between them.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Sin` takes [Radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). You can convert to Radians by using `yourNumber * Math.PI / 180`.

Answer (score 0):

[Math.Sin Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sin.aspx)

Math.Sin argument need to be in radians and not in degrees.

Comment: For english speakers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sin.aspx